# how to increase the size of array or free the memory after each iteration. Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I read data from a text file which is 27 MB file and contains 10001 rows, I need to handle large data. I perform some kind of processing in each row of data and then write it back to a text file. This is the code I have am using

```
StreamReader streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("D:\\input.txt");
        string lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();
        int count = 0;
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\ft1.txt"))
        {

            do
            {
                if (lineContent != null)
                {
                    string a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(lineContent).ToString();
                    string b = "[" + a + "]";
                    List<TweetModel> deserializedUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TweetModel>>(b);
                    var CreatedAt = deserializedUsers.Select(user => user.created_at).ToArray();

                    var Text = deserializedUsers.Where(m => m.text != null).Select(user => new
                    {
                        a = Regex.Replace(user.text, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty)
                        .Replace(@"\/", "/")
                        .Replace("\\", @"\")
                        .Replace("\'", "'")
                        .Replace("\''", "''")
                        .Replace("\n", " ")
                        .Replace("\t", " ")
                    }).ToArray();
                    var TextWithTimeStamp = Text[0].a + " (timestamp:" + CreatedAt[0] + ")";
                    writer.WriteLine(TextWithTimeStamp);
                }
                lineContent = streamReader.ReadLine();

            }
            while (streamReader.Peek() != -1);
            streamReader.Close();
```

This code helps does well up to 54 iterations as I get 54 lines in the output file. After that it gives error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." at line

```
var TextWithTimeStamp = Text[0].a + " (timestamp:" + CreatedAt[0] + ")";
```

I am not very clear about the issue if the maximum capacity of array has been violated, if so how can I increase it or If I can write the individual line encountered in loop through

```
writer.WriteLine(TextWithTimeStamp);
```

And clean the storage or something that can solve this issue. I tried using list insead of array , still issue is the same.Please help.

Comment: I guess `Text` or `CreatedAt` is an empty collection and thus cause the error. Did you step through the code to inspect the values of `Text` and `CreatedAt`?

Comment: Change that line to `var TextWithTimeStamp = (Text.Any() ? Text.First().a : string.Empty) + " (timestamp:" + (CreatedAt.Any() ? CreatedAt.First() : string.Empty) + ")";` for `m.text == null` and other scenarios, arrays might be empty.

Comment: Thanx @ArghyaC It worked. Some rows did not contain that data , I forgot to check that condition.

Comment: @khusbugupta added as answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
var TextWithTimeStamp = Text[0].a + " (timestamp:" + CreatedAt[0] + ")";
```

to

```
var TextWithTimeStamp = (Text.Any() ? Text.First().a : string.Empty) + 
            " (timestamp:" + (CreatedAt.Any() ? CreatedAt.First() : string.Empty) + ")";
```

As you are creating `Text` and `CreatedAt` collection objects, they might be empty (0 total item) based on some scenarios and conditions.

Those cases, `Text[0]` and `CreatedAt[0]` will fail. So, before using the first element, check if there are any items in the collection. `Linq` method `Any()` is used for that purpose.

**Update**

If you want to skip the lines that do not contain text, change this lines

```
var TextWithTimeStamp = Text[0].a + " (timestamp:" + CreatedAt[0] + ")";
writer.WriteLine(TextWithTimeStamp);
```

to

```
if (Text.Any())
{
    var TextWithTimeStamp = Text.First().a + " (timestamp:" + CreatedAt.First() + ")";
    writer.WriteLine(TextWithTimeStamp);
}
```

**Update 2**

To include all the `strings`s from `CreatedAt` rather than only the first one, you can add all the values in comma separated strings. A general example

```
var strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var allStrings = string.Join(",", strings); //"a,b,c"
```

Comment: what if I want to skip the lines that does not contain text instead of simply adding timestamp to string.Empty and collect only those strings that contain Text?

Comment: Thanks for the update and also if there are many values and I don't want to include only the first one and avoid the rest. How do I include number of values contained. For example, If CreatedAt contained number of values and I want to include all of them. If I leave CreatedAt as it is, it will write System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] in the text file. How do I obtain the number of values contained in CreatedAt avoiding the .First() and including all.